# Eliminate not up-to-date values within each factor level

Tags: r

I am currently working with a data frame similar to the following:

```
CompanyID  Share.ID  share.2011  date.2011  share.2012  date.2012
A          X         70.00       2011-07-01
A          Y         70.00       2011-12-01
A          Z                                60.00       2012-12-01
B          K         100.00      2011-09-01
B          L                                100.00      2012-12-01
...
```

`CompanyID` is the identifier for the observed companies. `Share.ID` is the identifier for the majority shareholder of the firm. `date.20XX` stands for the date of the information. `share.20XX` is the share held by the shareholder.

My problem is now as follows. The data is structured in a way that in one year, 2 or more shareholders can show up with majority shares (e.g., X,Y for company A in 2011), which is wrong. I now need to find a way to eliminate the less current data point (i.e., the data point with the less current `date.2011`), so that:

Within each `Company.ID`level, if there are 2 shares in , say, `share.2011`, overwrite the value with `""` for the share that was entered into the database earlier (i.e. that has an earlier date in `date.2011`)

The final table would then look as follows:

```
CompanyID  Share.ID  share.2011  date.2011  share.2012  date.2012
A          X                     2011-07-01
A          Y         70.00       2011-12-01
A          Z                                60.00       2012-12-01
B          K         100.00      2011-09-01
B          L                                100.00      2012-12-01
...
```

Thank you! I have tried several options involving subsetting, but always failed so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operations like this are more straightforward when your data are in long format.

```
library(dplyr)
```

Convert data to long format:

```
dat.long = reshape(dat, varying=3:6, direction="long", timevar="year")
```

> ```
>        CompanyID Share.ID year share       date id
> 1.2011         A        X 2011    70 2011-07-01  1
> 2.2011         A        Y 2011    70 2011-12-01  2
> 3.2011         A        Z 2011    NA       <NA>  3
> 4.2011         B        K 2011   100 2011-09-01  4
> 5.2011         B        L 2011    NA       <NA>  5
> 1.2012         A        X 2012    NA       <NA>  1
> 2.2012         A        Y 2012    NA       <NA>  2
> 3.2012         A        Z 2012    60 2012-12-01  3
> 4.2012         B        K 2012    NA       <NA>  4
> 5.2012         B        L 2012   100 2012-12-01  5
> ```

Filter to just the majority shareholder for each `CompanyID` in each `year`:

```
dat.long %>% 
  # Remove rows with no share data
  filter(!is.na(share)) %>%
  # Convert date to date format
  mutate(date=as.Date(date)) %>%
  # Operate by group
  group_by(CompanyID, year) %>%
  # Sort data
  arrange(CompanyID, year, date) %>%
  # Keep only the most recent date within each group
  slice(n())
```

> ```
>   CompanyID Share.ID  year share       date    id
> 1         A        Y  2011    70 2011-12-01     2
> 2         A        Z  2012    60 2012-12-01     3
> 3         B        K  2011   100 2011-09-01     4
> 4         B        L  2012   100 2012-12-01     5
> ```

In the example above, I removed all rows except the majority share holders. If you want to keep the non-majority-shareholder rows but set them to `NA`, you can do this:

```
dat.long %>% 
  filter(!is.na(share)) %>%
  mutate(date=as.Date(date)) %>%
  group_by(CompanyID, year) %>%
  arrange(CompanyID, year, date) %>%
  mutate(share = ifelse(date==max(date), share, NA))
```

> ```
>   CompanyID Share.ID  year share       date    id
> 1         A        X  2011    NA 2011-07-01     1
> 2         A        Y  2011    70 2011-12-01     2
> 3         A        Z  2012    60 2012-12-01     3
> 4         B        K  2011   100 2011-09-01     4
> 5         B        L  2012   100 2012-12-01     5
> ```

Comment: Hi @eipi10 - this worked very well, thank you very much. Especially the 'reshape' function was new to me but seems very useful!